# retrieving stream story impressions for an application

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm struggling with facebook FQL- i need to know how many impressions the steam stories generated by the app got.

In the FQL table there is an app_id column- if i could just select where app_id = '' then that would be me flying but since its not an indexed column fql spits out and error

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

I know every post made returns a post id- which i currently do not store but if it meant storing every ID and then doing a massive query to count each individuals post impressions then so be it...

but there has to be an easier way (especially when I get thousands of posts being generated by users)

Comment: Stream stories where? Posted on a user's wall? Do you want to ask for all of the impressions that the stories your app generated anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for, FQL wise is not possible since you can only use "indexable" columns in the WHERE clause.
The "app_id" column is not indexable (there's no '*') and so you can't use that.

You can, as you said save the post id and then ask about specific posts or you can use the "source_id" which is also indexable to query all of the posts your application made to a user wall (or a page wall).

Also, you should be able to use the IN clause, so you'll end up with something like:

```
SELECT post_id, impressions
FROM stream
WHERE
    source_id IN (SOME IDS OF USERS)
    AND
    app_id = YOUR APP ID
```

Comment: thanks for this- but would this query work if i passed 2000 facebook IDs into the array?

Comment: Probably no, don't forget you are also restricted by the length of the http request... I suggest that using that method you can break it into groups of users. You can also use the [Btach Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) api.